# How to override carousel.phtml file in Magento 2 custom theme

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, parent-child-theme, template-override

I want to override below Page builder Carousel phtml file in my custom theme. Please provide magento standard way for this.

```
vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/widget/content/carousel.phtml
```

I have already placed this file in custom theme but it's not working.

FYI, After executing the grep command for the above file & found the below reference core files but could not get the exact idea of how to override the above carousel.phtml file.

```
grep -r 'carousel.phtml' vendor/
vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/adminhtml/web/ts/js/content-type/products/mass-converter/carousel-widget-directive.ts:            template: "Magento_PageBuilder::catalog/product/widget/content/carousel.phtml",
vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/adminhtml/web/js/content-type/products/mass-converter/carousel-widget-directive.js:        template: "Magento_PageBuilder::catalog/product/widget/content/carousel.phtml",
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Custom Module and then you can override this carousel.phtml file.

Vendor_Module

You just create a registration.php file, a etc/module.xml file.
And then create your view/ folder and with same path override this phtml file.

view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/widget/content/carousel.phtml

run all commands.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, In my case, I forgot to apply my custom theme on the admin side. It's working fine now with my custom theme. I hope this comment helps others.